# VS2013 ERROR 0xC0000005: when using libcurl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcurl

I'm trying to use libcurl (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) for downloading data from a web, and store these data in a txt file , and here is my code:

```
// CLASS SinaStk

size_t save_data(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* userdata){


locale loc = std::locale::global(std::locale("")); //TRY TO OPEN FILE WITH CHINESE

userdata = fopen(fpath.c_str(), "w");
if (userdata == NULL)
printf("File not open!\n");
locale::global(loc);
size_t writelen=size * nmemb;

fwrite(buffer, size, nmemb, userdata);

return writelen;
};

virtual void downloadUrl()   
{
    CURL* stkCURL=NULL;
    CURLcode res;
    FILE * fp=NULL;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);  
    stkCURL = curl_easy_init();    

    curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_URL,"http://hq.sinajs.cn/list=s_sh000001"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &SinaStk::save_data); 
    curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,fp);
    res=curl_easy_perform(stkCURL);                  //<-STOP!!!!

    fclose(fp);
    curl_easy_cleanup(stkCURL);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return;
};
```

and when I debug my code, it always stop and then jump to xstring:

```
    size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return length of sequence
      return (this->_Mysize);                  // <-STOP!!! 
    }
```

0xC0000005:  Access violation reading location 0x0000009E

I have no idea about the problem for almost a week. I am upset, I asked people around me and nobody knows why.

Thanks for reading, I am really confused.

=============

Problem is solved! Thanks you guys! now my code is:

```
//CLASS StkApiInfo
size_t writeData(char* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb){
    if (stkFile.is_open()){
        stkFile.close();
        stkFile.clear();
    };
    fpath = "D:\\Code\\代码\\数据文件\\" + fname + ".txt";
    stkFile.open(fpath.c_str(), ios::out);
    //if (stkFile.is_open())
    cout << buffer<<size<<nmemb;
    stkFile << buffer<<endl;
    stkFile.close();
    stkFile.clear();
    return size*nmemb;
};

//CLASS SinaStk : public StkApiInfo
static size_t save_data(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata){

    SinaStk* self = (SinaStk*)userdata;
    return self->writeData(buffer, size, nmemb);
};

virtual void downloadUrl()  
{
    CURL* stkCURL = NULL;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32); 
    stkCURL = curl_easy_init();  
    if (stkCURL)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_URL, stkUrl.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &SinaStk::save_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
        res = curl_easy_perform(stkCURL);
        //if (res != CURLE_OK)
        curl_easy_cleanup(stkCURL);
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }

    return;
};
```

Comment: Can you post a small but complete (compilable) examble where the error occurs?

Comment: You should check your return values and not just assume those functions work.  `curl_easy_init` returns NULL if there is an issue.  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html  Look at the example on that page -- you are not checking if the return value is not NULL.  The same thing with all of those other functions -- each one returns a code stating an error occurred or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your answer! Actually, I delete some if-null sentence to simplify my question. I do checked the return value of `stkCURL = curl_easy_init();`  and stkURL isn't NULL

Comment: a read/write violation location of `0x0000009E` is *highly* suspect of being a NULL pointer dereference. If I had to put money on it, somewhere there is a NULL pointer of a structure with a member 158-bytes in from the structure base that is trying to be read. I'd set a breakpoint in `SinaStk::save_data` and step through it, assuming everything is dandy up until the perform call.

Comment: @noxeve What about your callback function?  You check if the file handle is valid, but you go ahead and use it anyway eve if it's NULL.

Comment: @noxeve You never stated what exactly solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Callback passed with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` argument should be of type [write_callback](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) (with exact that signature) and therefore cannot be non-static class method. Usual workaround is to define callback as non-member or static method and pass `this` as an argument:

```
static size_t save_data(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata)
{
    SinaStk* self = (SinaStk*) userdata;
    return self->doStuff(buffer, size, nmemb);
}

virtual void downloadUrl()   
{
    //...
    curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &SinaStk::save_data); 
    curl_easy_setopt(stkCURL, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
    //...
}
```

If you need to access additional data (like `FILE*` in your example) you can either store it as class field or introduce temporary structure that would contain `this` and additional data fields and pass it's address as callback argument.

Comment: The compiler would (or should have) given an error if the function signatures didn't match.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `curl_easy_setopt` is generic function that accepts option code and argument, so compiler has no reason to complain. see it's definition [here](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/include/curl/easy.h#L29)

Comment: Might as well call the function "curl_easy_setopt_dangerous".  If that's the case, then an alternate answer would be to wrap that function in a type-safe wrapper that would have checked the signature.